# multiple if Else condition

Tags: javascript

hi i want to check if these parameters exists... if they do not they will be false...

INITIALLY

```
var version_name_checker, 
    version_code_checker,
    ext_data_checker,
    package_name_checker,
    stacktrace_checker = true
```

THEN

```
version_name_checker = (!version_name_checker) ? false : !utile.isNullOrEmpty(query.version_name);
```

SAME FOR OTHERS

If any or all of these exist I want to add them to database. I want to know different ways I can do this. One way I do this is using if else

if all are true add them to db
otherwise separate if if for each of them...

Is there any other effective way to do it?

Comment: It seems a basic conditional statement. Please, make an effort by yourself and then came back if you have a specific problem

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "exist" in this case. Does "existence" mean that a value has been assigned to them? Does it mean that a **non-null** value has been assigned to them? Does it mean that a non-"falsey" value has been assigned to them?

Comment: i edited question pls check

Answer (score 1):

the best way to achieve this is assign default values:

```
    var version_name_checker, version_code_checker,ext_data_checker,package_name_checker,stacktrace_checker = true

//... your code

var DEFAULT_VERSION_NAME = "1.0.0.9";
//var version_name_checker = "abc";
version_name_checker = version_name_checker || DEFAULT_VERSION_NAME;

alert(version_name_checker);
```

jsFiddle available here: https://jsfiddle.net/3rwq13t2/

edit: can also use const instead of var if you're targeting ECMAScript v6:

https://jsfiddle.net/3rwq13t2/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can put them all in an array, and use some array functions to find if any or all are a particular state

```
var arr = [version_name_checker, 
    version_code_checker,
    ext_data_checker,
    package_name_checker,
    stacktrace_checker];

// are all of them true?
var allTrue = (arr.filter(i => i == true).length == arr.length);

// are any false
var anyFalse = arr.some(i => i == false);
```

There are plenty of permutations of functionality you could do with similar methods.